# Generic Type toArray and asList

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to understand generics and I purposely want to generate a classcastexception, however, i instead get an arraystoreexception on the first attempt.

```
    static <E> E reduce(List<E> list, Function<E> f, E initVal) {

    E[] snapshot = (E[]) list.toArray();

    Object[] o = snapshot;
    o[0] = new Long(1);

    E result =  initVal;
    for (E e : snapshot)
        result = f.apply(result, e);


    return result;
}


private static final Function<Integer> SUM = new Function<Integer>(){
    public Integer apply(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
        return i1 + i2;
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(2, 7);
    System.out.println(reduce(intList, SUM, 0));
}
```

On the second attempt.. I correctly get a ClassCastException using this...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> intList1 = Arrays.asList(2, 7);
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(intList1);
    System.out.println(reduce(intList, SUM, 0));
}
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Just as a side note, java naming conventions follow a `lowerCaseCamel` for function/method names

Comment: @Jimmy he's following the convention. What method are you referring to?

Comment: Wait, wait.  What are the two lines `Object[] o = snapshot; o[0] = new Long(1);` doing there?  Are you trying to force an `ArrayStoreException`?

Answer (score 3):

It appears to me that the List instance produced by Arrays.asList() does not properly implement the contract of the toArray() method.  From List.toArray() javadoc:

```
Note that toArray(new Object[0]) is identical in function to toArray().
```

However note the following test:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
  System.out.println(Arrays.asList(2, 7).toArray());
  System.out.println(Arrays.asList(2, 7).toArray(new Object[0]));
}
```

and output:

```
[Ljava.lang.Integer;@3e25a5
[Ljava.lang.Object;@19821f
```

Note that according to the javadoc, toArray() should produce an array of type Object[], but `Arrays.<E>asList().toArray()` instead produces an array of type E[].

The reason you get an ArrayStoreException is because your array is of type Integer[] when it should be of type Object[].

Comment: Nice catch. Is this a JRE bug that's been hiding since 1.5?

Comment: Note, this was fixed in Java 9

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're creating an array. Just do this:

```
static <E> E reduce(List<E> list, Function<E> f, E initVal) {
    for (E e : list)
        initVal = f.apply(initVal, e);
    return initVal;
}
```

See: [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: In Java, generics and arrays don't work well together... unfortunately.